# Filtered tasklist piped into find doesn't show console output?

Tags: batch-file, console, find, tasklist

Windows XP Pro

This shows output in the console:

```
dir | find " free"
```

This doesn't:

```
tasklist | find "Image Name"
```

This *does*:

```
tasklist | find /C "Image Name"
```

And this *does* write the expected line into the file:

```
tasklist | find "Image Name" > foo.txt
```

What causes that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
> tasklist | find "Image Name"
Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
```

Can't reproduce here. Your second command line does work as expected and that way no confusion arises when the fourth one writes that line into a file.

Did you perhaps still have the leading space in the string to search from the previous line when you searched for `" free"`?

Comment: I executed exactly what is seen in the question.  I had a second pair of eyes examine what I was doing before I brought the question here, and I was very careful to make sure the question was representative.  I'm sure it's some Console oddity on this end.  Very strange.

Answer (score 4):

what about findstr? have you tried?

```
C:\test>tasklist  | findstr "Image Name"
Image Name                   PID Session Name     Session#    Mem Usage
```

Comment: Yeah, I think that worked, but the actual need I'm after uses the /C flag of find.

Answer (score 0):

if /C flag showed that a particular line was found, maybe the string returned by 'find' was somehow stripped (or there as a special character in the string) and only the end of the string was displayed? What would happen if you'd resize the command line window?

Here is a fix:

`tasklist | find "3184" | sort`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Stack Overflow, I learned [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766211/tasklist-output-used-in-pipe-is-broken) a while back.  (Apparently I should probably comment instead of answer here, but I don't have the rep yet.)  Read the link, but the summary is that the output of tasklist.exe has some non-printing garbage that is fixed by redirecting standard error to NUL: `tasklist.exe 2>NUL | find "Image Name"`